# Elasticsearch: Changing data directory on an Amazon Linux Machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed Elasticsearch on an Amazon Linux Machine using the latest `rpm` package from their website. After thatt, I have attached an EBS volume and created a directory on this volume. I want this directory to be the data directory of Elasticsearch. So, I started the elasticsearch service first with defaults. I created a new directory in the user `ec2-user` home directory

```
mkdir my_data
```

Then I changed the path.data in the `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` file to point to this new directory

```
path.data: /home/ec2-user/my_data
```

Then I changed the ownership of this directory:

```
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /home/ec2-user/my_data
```

So, currently the permissions look like this

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXX ~]$ ls -lrt
total 28632
drwxrwxr-x 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch     4096 Feb  4 06:18 my_data
```

However, when I try to start elasticsearch, I get the error:

```
Starting elasticsearch: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/home/ec2-user/my_data)
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/ec2-user/my_data
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:383)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:630)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:734)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:720)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:256)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:196)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: ES needs right permission to be able to write data to the new directory. do `ls -l` and check the permission and then use `chmod`

Comment: I ran this command to make sure elasticsearch is the new owner. `sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /new/data/directory`

Comment: Although `cp -rp` had already taken care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it surprising, but in the latest version of Elasticsearch, if you create a data directory inside home of other user, ES is unable to access it. Though logically it is perfect too. What i suggest that you either mount an external hard disk for elasticsearch or create a data directory inside /home/ on the parallel of ec2-user. so you directory should have a path /home/my-data and it will work like a charm. :)

Thanks ,
Bharvi

Comment: in MySQL I can add user=root in my.cnf so that mysql can write to any folder. Is there a similar setting in Elastic?

Comment: Same here; can neither use `/home/ec2-user` to store the data/logs nor to read configuration from... baffled 

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone with the problem that I was seeing...

This seems to be an oddity with `java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories`. The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) says "Unlike the createDirectory method, an exception is not thrown if the directory could not be created because it already exists." In your case, the folder exists so you should not get an exception. But the check for existence done in [UnixFileSystemProvider](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/323b53b10644/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystemProvider.java#l372) is via `mkdir` which will throw an access-denied exception before it throws an already-exists exception. The access-denied exception which you are seeing then is not that elasticsearch doesn't have access to `/home/ec2-user/my_data` but rather that it doesn't have access to make that directory. So the solution is to fix the permission problem that is preventing elasticsearch from *making the directory* `/home/ec2-user/my_data`. For you this would be to make `/home/ec2-user` writeable by elasticsearch or to create a path like `/home/ec2-user/my_data_holder/my_data` and then make `/home/ec2-user/my_data_holder` writeable by elasticsearch.